# Imagen en html que sirva como input type file

Tags: html, css

estoy creando un apartado para que el usuario pueda subir archivos al servidor, para que sea mas intuitivo planeo que al hacerle clic en la imagen se abra el apartado para seleciconar el documento, de momento solo tengo la imagen pero no se como hacerle para que pueda cumplir la funcion del input type file, les muestro el codigo

```
<div class="form-group" align="center">
            <label>Ingrese el ID del empleado</labe><br>
            <input type="text" class="redondeado">   
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" align="center">
            <img src="images/upload2.png"><br><br>
        </div>
```

Espero y alguien me pueda orientar como realizarlo, de antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer esto:

En tu css

```
.form-group>input {
  display: none;
}
```

En tu html:

```
<div class="form-group" align="center">
  <label for="file-input">
    <img src="https://icon-library.net/images/upload-photo-icon/upload-photo-icon-21.jpg"/>
  </label>

  <input id="file-input" type="file" />
</div>
```